# Update the ID of a model in symfony

Tags: forms, symfony1, model

I am currently using the symfony admin-generator a manipulate a database. The database is already created and in use and one of the things it does differently than what a normally setup symfony database does is use a varchar as a primary key rather than symfony's method of using ints for all primary keys.

The problem I am having is being able to edit and update this primary key in a form. The issue is that, when I try to edit the key, the form throws an error and says "Invalid". The error, I can assume, comes from the fact that the new PK does not match the old one. I suppose I have these options:

1. Delete the old model, create a new one and save it.
2. Do not allow them to edit the ID. They will have to delete the model instead and recreate it.
3. Do not allow them to make or edit the ID and instead infer it from an attribute.
4. Change the database architecture so that the model has an auto-increment integer PK. Then use a unique varchar index for the previous PK.

Now that I think about it, number 3 would be ideal because the model as a "Name" field, which could easily have an ID inferred from it. However, this would still cause the issue in 1 when they update the name.

I do not like option 2 at all, and I think I would actually prefer number 4. I assume 4 is the easiest way and it could be done, but I would like to at least know if number 1 could be implemented for future reference.

Comment: Why do you have editable PKs? What information (that is user-editable) do they store?

Comment: This model in this case is a Category. The PK is a short, descriptive slug. For instance, the Category may be named "Sports & Recreation" however, the PK would be something like "sports". It's used in order to prevent duplicate categories.

Comment: If it's an option, might be better to use an integer primary key column and add a unique constraint on the categories if there's a chance that duplicates may occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment response I would refactor the database. I'd create an auto_increment integer PK and create a unique index on the slug column.